# C# mysql UPDATE and SELECT in one button

Tags: c#, mysql, select, button

Im beginner in C#, but i have to make one software for friend. Its for generating numbers (they are in mysql). I have number in label and button. This button is for generate next number from MySQL (it SELECT number from database, which was not used).
My code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string input = label1.Text.Trim();
            string conn = "server=46.28.110.147;user=______;password=________;database=________;";
            MySqlConnection myconn = new MySqlConnection(conn);
            string sql = "SELECT numbers FROM domestic WHERE used=0 ORDER BY numbers LIMIT 1";
            string sq2 = "UPDATE domestic SET used = 1 WHERE numbers = '" + label1.Text +"'";
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, myconn);
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sq2, myconn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

                myconn.Open();    
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();    
                myconn.Close(); 

                label1.Text = dt.Rows[0][0] + "";

        }
```

Problem is when i click on button. 
1) click on button - it make UPDATE (**without SELECT**)  (it set used = 1 to number in database, which is in label)
2) click on button again - it make **only** SELECT  (it takes next number from databse with used = 0)
3) click on button - it make **only** UPDATE (**without SELECT**)
4) clcik on button - AGAIN from step 2 to 3

Please, can you tell me, how can i do both operations (UPDATE and SELECT) in only one click?

Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks like it currently behaves as follows:

1. Defines `SELECT` statement using a constant SQL query.
2. **Defines `UPDATE` statement using the content of the label text (maybe empty?)**
3. Fills a datatable with a `MySqlDataAdapter`. It must be recovering the first available number from your database.
4. Opens a connection and executes the update.
5. Recovers de first column of first datarow filled in point 3.

I think that the problem in this case is that you are mixing code to reach the solution. Try this:

1. Define `SELECT` statement using a constant SQL query.
2. Fill a datatable with a MySqlDataAdapter.
3. Recover the first column of first datarow filled in point 2 and populate value to the label text.
4. Define `UPDATE` statement using the content of the label text (this
   time has the number recovered in the last step.
5. Open a connection and execute the update.

Something like...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string input = label1.Text.Trim();
    string conn = "server=46.28.110.147;user=______;password=________;database=________;";
    MySqlConnection myconn = new MySqlConnection(conn);
    string sql = "SELECT numbers FROM domestic WHERE used=0 ORDER BY numbers LIMIT 1";
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, myconn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    label1.Text = dt.Rows[0][0] + "";   // Recovers the value and puts into label.

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sq2, myconn);
    string sq2 = "UPDATE domestic SET used = 1 WHERE numbers = '" + label1.Text +"'";
    myconn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();              // Updates database to set used = 1 for recovered number.
    myconn.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string input = label1.Text.Trim();
    string conn = "server=46.28.110.147;user=______;password=________;database=________;";
    string sql = "SELECT numbers FROM domestic WHERE used=0 ORDER BY numbers LIMIT 1; UPDATE domestic SET used = 1 WHERE numbers = @numbers";
    MySqlConnection myconn = new MySqlConnection(conn);
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, myconn);
    MySqlDataAdapter da = null;
    DataSet ds = null;
    DataTable dt = null;

    cmd.Parameters.Add("numbers", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = input;

    da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);

    if (ds.Tables.Count > 0) {
        if (ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0) {
            dt = ds.Tables(0);
            label1.Text = dt.Rows(0)(0) + "";
        }
    }
}
```